# Make unique table for different user in Php

Tags: php, html, database

I have an php page which has a database associated to it. For different user coming to my page, i want to generate a unique table to enter their details. I want to generate this name somehow from the url so that if same user logs in again i can use the same table made earlier for him. I am new to php and i have no idea on how to do this.

```
<html>
   <head>
      <title>PHP Script</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <?php
         echo "<h1>Hello, User!</h1>";
         /* i want to get a unique name for creating a table
         in the database corresponding to the user who logged in
         so that i can enter all details collected from the user
         to a unique table */
      ?>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Creating a table per user is how you create a schema that's completely unmaintainable and will blow up any SQL management tool you connect to your server. I'd *strongly* advise against doing this.

Comment: In addition to being a bad idea, as @tadman notes, SO questions usually require that you make a best-effort at implementing your idea, then coming with a question if something doesn't work or doesn't work as expected.

Comment: @MarcL.Sorry about the poor quality of the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many soultions to your question. The best approach is to use [Routing](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/routing) with php framework.
Another and simple way is ti use `GET` like this:

URL: `http://example.com/?user=sky`

And in PHP:

```
<?php
   $username = $_GET['user'];
   //Now you got the username. You can load user info with this
```

Comment: Routing is usually way better than super ugly URLs like `/?user=XXX`. Laravel does a great job of keeping your URLs clean. Good recommendation.